# How to setup your Linux server to execute a php script every minute

Tags: php, linux

How can I setup my Linux server to execute a particular php-script automatically every minute?

Thank you.

Comment: Start at the manpage for `crontab`

Comment: I was curious if the first search result on google for the title of this question was a page about crontab.. and it was :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under linux you can use crontab by specifying full path of your script, for example:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/biji/script.php
```

Or if you put the script on web, you can use wget

```
*/2 * * * * wget http://yourserver/script.php -O /dev/null
```

If you need more enterprise solution, you can use job queue using zend server (but it will be costly):

> http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/zend-server-job-queue

Answer (score 2):

Try a [Cron Job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 1):

Use cron.

Reference

- http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html
- http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/schedule_tasks_on_linux_using_crontab/

Comment: Thanks that link 2end link really helped out.  That was really easy